# Bootstrap Datetimepicker with dynamic mirror fields

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I'm using http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ and I have this snippet:

```
<div class="input-group date form_datetime">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startDateTime" id="startDateTime">
    <input type="hidden" id="startDateTime_mirror" name="startDateTime_mirror">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default date-set" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Please notice that the `input[type=text]` and the `input[type=hidden]` fields have the same `id`, but the latter with a `_mirror` suffix

Since I have a couple of datepickers in a page (i.e. also `endDateTime` and `endDateTime_mirror`), I can't use a 'fixed' mirror field id as in datetimepicker's demo page

EDIT: an example of two datetimepickers

```
<div class="input-group date form_datetime">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startDateTime" id="startDateTime">
    <input type="hidden" id="startDateTime_mirror" name="startDateTime_mirror">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default date-set" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="input-group date form_datetime">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endDateTime" id="endDateTime">
    <input type="hidden" id="endDateTime_mirror" name="endDateTime_mirror">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default date-set" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work (even if the 'generated' name is right, `startDateTime_mirror` (I can see it in `console.log()`):

```
$(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: "dd MM yyyy hh:ii",
    linkField: ($(this).find('.form-control').prop('id')) + '_mirror',
    linkFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii"
})
```

Any help, please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to put each couple of datepicker in a separate div that you would describe with an id:

```
<div class="input-group date form_datetime" id="startBlock">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startDateTime" id="startDateTime">
    <input type="hidden" id="startDateTime_mirror" name="startDateTime_mirror">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default date-set" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="input-group date form_datetime" id="endBlock">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endDateTime" id="endDateTime">
    <input type="hidden" id="endDateTime_mirror" name="endDateTime_mirror">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default date-set" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#startBlock").datetimepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
        linkField: "startDateTime_mirror",
        linkFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii"
    });

    $("#endBlock").datetimepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
        linkField: "endDateTime_mirror",
        linkFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Then can you post your complete code with the two couples of datepickers ?

Comment: I just put the two datetimepickers: it's just like your example, but with an only block of JS

Comment: But you need to have two "blocks" since `$(".form_datetime")` actually means that you are selecting all the DOM elements whose class name is form_datetime and in your case you have two of them.
The part `.datepicker(...)` is meant to apply on only one of those elements.